# Eclipse - [file name] cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a file in eclipse and whenever it is being used, i get [file name] cannot be resolved. I have tried to clean/install , have tried to refresh. Eclipse see's the file, even suggests to import it. When i import it, it then says 'import not being used' even though it is being used. When it is being used, the file shows as an error saying it cannot resolve the type. What is going on? have been trying for hours to resolve this. Is there a trick to fix this?

Comment: Try to imagine somebody came to you and asked this question exactly in the way you've stated it. Would you have any idea where to start? You haven't even told us what kind of file it is, or how you created it, or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you've provided, you could try this copying your code into an already existing file that works fine and run it.

If this works then look at your file creation again... if not, give a more detailed description of your problem.

Comment: This feels like it would have worked better as a comment rather than an answer...getting more info first, then posting a solution once you have the info you need.